# Can we write scala class inside the java project package?

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I create a **scala** class inside a **java project package**

but the **problem** is that scala class is not visible in other java classes (just import it but not visible)

I don't know if this possible the creation of scala class inside a java package..

Please share your answers..

with regards

Milano

**EDIT**

The **studentDAO** and **Student** classes are **Scala classes** but that located in **java package**

the service  package is a scala package and dao and domain package is java package

```
import com.model.dao.StudentDAO
import com.model.domain.entity.Student

@Service("studentService")
class StudentServiceImpl extends StudentService {
  @Autowired
  val studentDao: StudentDAO=null
  @Override
  def updateStudentById(id: Long){

  }
  @Override
  def saveStudentDetails(student: Student) {
    studentDao.save(student)
  }
  @Override
  def updateStudentDetails(student: Student) {
    studentDao.update(student)
  }
```

the Import stmt shows compilation error that the Class is not visible

Comment: Should be possible. Can you post your example code (cut down) ?

Comment: Yes it is possible and there should not be problems. Could you provide shortened example (code) of class/classes that do not play well together?

Comment: i got compilation error when import scala class ...

i create this  by  just copy from file and paste on the package

Comment: Please edit your question rather than post comments

Comment: The type com.model.domain.entity.Student is not visible this is the compilation error shows

Comment: Wich IDE and compiler settings do you use?

Comment: Is your project a Java project, or a Scala project? Did you add the scala library to the project?

Comment: @AlexIv i use eclipse Juno compiler jbose

Comment: @zsxwing it'aa multiple module projects.. the dao and domain uses java and service use scala and also the the java module contain scala library

Comment: Are you compiling it using the scala compiler?

Comment: @Impredicative Yes and server Jboss